# Bizarre css selector combination

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

This is my code:

`HTML`

```
<div id="corner">
    <div id="cornerbox"></div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
#corner {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
}
#corner #cornerbox {
    background-color:black;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
#corner:hover  #cornerbox, #corner #cornerbox.show{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

`JavaScript`

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
        //console.log("keypress event from document: ",e.which);
        if (e.which == 63) {    // question mark (?) key
            $("#cornerbox").toggleClass("show");
        }
});
```

[JSFiddle Code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/gotoandrun/thgPF/)

So CSS makes "#cornerbox" change opacity whenever #corner:hover, and JavaScript toggles class "show" of "#cornerbox" whenever the question mark (?) key is pressed.

I've noticed that if I change the above CSS to look like this:

```
#corner {
    ...
}
#corner #cornerbox {
    ...
}
#corner:hover #cornerbox, #cornerbox.show {
    ...
}
```

the opacity is not changed when (?) key is pressed, but "#cornerbox" receives class "show".

All other possibilities work.

This works.

```
#corner {
    ...
}
#cornerbox {
    ...
}
#corner:hover #cornerbox, #corner #cornerbox.show {
    ...
}
```

And this works.

```
#corner {
    ...
}
#cornerbox {
    ...
}
#corner:hover #cornerbox, #cornerbox.show {
    ...
}
```

Why?

Thank you in advance!

Tase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That happens because the selector `#cornerbox.show` has lesser [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) than `#corner #cornerbox`, which means that it is incapable of overriding it.

If you increase the specificity of `#cornerbox.show` by adding an id selector, or decrease that of `#corner #cornerbox` by removing an id selector the new state of affairs allows the second selector to override.